# How do I access a variable defined in another function?

Tags: python, abaqus

I am trying to call a variable in one function from another in `Python`.

I tried returning the desired variables then putting them as inputs in the second function but it tells me that they are not defined. I don't know why it's doing this.

Basically, I want to use the `Steps` list from `Create_Array()` inside the `Edit_PPress()` function without having to request user input again to ask which test, since this would be an inconvenience to the user.

```
def Create_Array():
    outside_range = True
    while outside_range == True:
        test=getInput('What test?\n\n1 for Test A\n\n2 for TestB\n\n3 for Test C')
        if test == '1':
            Steps = [1,2,3]
            outside_range = False
            return Steps
        elif test == '2':
            Steps = [4,5,6]
            outside_range = False
            return Steps
        elif test == '3':
            Steps = [7,8,9]
            outside_range = False
            return Steps
        else:
            getWarningReply('Input is outside range. Please enter 1, 2, or 3.', "OKAY")
def Edit_PPress(Steps):
    print Steps
```

Which produces this error:

```
`<type 'TypeError'>: Edit_PPress() takes exactly 4 arguments (0 given)`
```

I am using it in Abaqus, so when I run Edit_PPress, it will be just like putting `Edit_PPress(Steps)` into the command prompt. I cannot create a class because Abaqus will not read functions inside of a class in its macro manager.

I am trying to call the `Steps` variable that is generated as a `list` in the `Create_Array()` function into the second function `Edit_PPress()`.  I would add my comments as comments, but the format on my browser is messed up and won't let me add comments. I can only edit my original question. Also...I did read the FAQ on how to ask a good question. What information am I missing?

**What I want to accomplish:** Use the Steps variable that is defined in the first function, in the second function.

**Problems:** tells me that the Steps variable is not defined when I attempt to run second function following first function.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Could you show how you are calling these functions, and provide the full error traceback?

Comment: it looks like you're confused about where to place the parameters.  Does this help you a bit: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c2429c27738c4f31fa94

Comment: Which variable do you want to call, specifically?

Comment: Take a few minutes to read StackOverflow's FAQs on how to ask a good question, and how the site works.  Edit your question to say specifically what your goal is, what you've tried (with a minimal code sample), and add your comments/discussions as comments rather than editing the answer--StackOverflow is a great place to get help, but really requires you to ask pointed and well formed questions to avoid them being closed.